# Replacing the content of the shared pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a shared pointer that I have shared around the system. Later on, I want to replace the actual content of these shared pointers point to, but still keep all the shared pointers valid, so they internally point to this new object.

Is there an easy way to do this with shared pointers?

Kind of like this I am looking for - pseudo-code

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Model> ModelPtr

ModelPtr model1 = ModelPtr(new Model);
ModelPtr model2 = model1;

// make something like 'model1.get() = new Model' so model1, model2 both points to a new model
```

EDIT:
I want the effect of this, but less gimicky

```
ModelPtr model1 = ModelPtr(new Model("monkey"));
memcpy(model1 .get(), new Model("donkey"), sizeof(Model));
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Model>>`?

Comment: Would `*model1 = Model{};` do what you need?

Comment: Could "placement new" help here?

Answer (score 14):

If I understood you correctly - you could use overloaded dereference operator:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<int>(42);
auto b = a;
*a = 43;

std::cout << *b << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
43
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `shared_ptr` instance has its own copy of the pointer, so there's no way for any one `shared_ptr` instance to know and affect the pointers of the other reference-counted `shared_ptr` instances.

Do you instead just want `model2` to be a *reference* to `model1` so that when you reset `model1`, model2 comes along with the change?

Otherwise can you elaborate further on the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Both model1 and model2 points to the same Model instance and the same memory location right? I want to alter the data at that memory location so it represents another Model instance - is that not possible?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan "the data at that memory location" *is* a Model instance. You can change the *value* of that data, and both pointers will point to the new value

Answer (score 1):

```
shared_ptr<char> p(new  char[256],std::default_delete<char[]>());
p.get()[0]='a';
```

memcpy do the job roughly.
You  may try to use  `reset` method, but only affect the caller object.